# How to create a new html file dynmically using HTML or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am sure that there are many tutorial that explains how can I do it, but I dont know how it called.

So what I want is somthing like this:

The user create is page, and he can hit "save" and a new html page created, for example:

At first the user in index.html, and when he hit save he will get into somthing like: ../username.html

How can I do that?

Comment: I think the best way is to save what the user types into a db, than with php retrive the saved content from the db and create the page afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

1. Save the page to the database using mysql or any other query language.

   1.1 Create a table e.g. "pages" with columns: filename | contents

   1.2 Now use mod_rewrite or nodejs routing to look up the filename in the requested path, select the contents from the database and send the contents to the user.
2. Save the file directly to the harddrive.

   2.1 in php you could use file_put_contents(filename, contents); and in nodejs you could use fs.writeFile(filename, data[, options], callback).

But it's important to keep in mind that the page contents could have malicious code in it. So you would need to double check the contents of the file.

The contents for the page should be send using the POST method. Here you could use a form with method="POST" or ajax with type: "post".

Answer (score 0):

You need something server side to dynamically generate the code for the page.  EG you have a static page name (user.php or user.aspx etc) and then depending what the user does, you populate the code on this page from the server.

It can be done on the client side using JS but it would be very very bad practice to have this level of processing happening in the client.